# Why does PersistentEntityResourceAssembler:getSingleResourceLinkTo uses entities instead of repositories to construct the single resource link?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I noticed in the latest spring-data release train `Gosling-RC1` something changed - looking at the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` I can see now the method `getSelfLinkFor` is now using `entities` to find the `PersistentEntity`. More precisely it's here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/f8c7a1c376f64b9a36f5bb6bf834458402fd8b09#diff-b5d65266b4181597ee26baed60291de6R195

Before it was using `repositories` and inside the `repositories` there's this recursive call:

```
    if (!userType.equals(Object.class)) {
        return getRepositoryFactoryInfoFor(userType.getSuperclass());
    }
```

which checks if the super class is not `Object` to try and use the super class. `PersistentEntities` class however does not have this recursive call:

```
        if (context.hasPersistentEntityFor(type)) {
            return context.getPersistentEntity(type);
        }
```

so now I get a different behaviour. I have a `Product` and a `MyProduct` which extends `Product`. For `Product` I have a repository, but for `MyProduct` I don't. Using the Gosling-M1 release train my links are rendered like this:

```
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost/rest/product/564546483459328{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
```

but when I upgrade to Gosling-RC1 they are rendered like this:

```
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://www.solarapparel.com/rest/myProductModel/564546483459328{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
```

and when I try to call `http://www.solarapparel.com/rest/myProductModel` it returns 404 because there is no such repository.

Is this a bug? Or is it a known behaviour and this is how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not, as you're comparing apples to oranges. When looking up repositories it's natural to also look for repositories of super types as the repositories can naturally also persist super types.

This is of course different when it comes to looking up persistence metadata for a particular type. Imagine you're looking for all fields of a particular type in the reflection API and it would just go ahead and inspect a super type. This would pretty obviously create invalid results.

The reason `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` uses `PersistentEntities` instead of a `Repositories` instance is – as the name suggests – that it also will be used to create `Resource` instances for entities that are not aggregate roots.